# Using Word OLE in Lazarus FreePascal

Tags: ms-word, freepascal, lazarus

Im trying to get FreePascal to open up a word document, append some text and data to it and then close it. I've managed to get connected and can write a single line to the document but anything over that is defeating me. Currently I am attempting methods details in [this Visual Basic reference](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316383), which is pretty similar to how I would expect FreePascal to handle things.

Basically I think I have misunderstood how the relationship between Lazarus and the Word OLE actually works, can anyone offer me any examples on how to construct a simple document that I can build on?

The following code, opens the document but then completely replaces its contents

```
program officAuto;

{$IFDEF FPC}
{$MODE Delphi}
{$ELSE}
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$ENDIF}

uses
   SysUtils, Variants, ComObj;

const
   ServerName = 'Word.Application';

var
   Server, Doc : Variant;
   oPara : Variant;
   w:widestring;

begin
   if Assigned(InitProc) then
   TProcedure(InitProc);

try
   Server := CreateOleObject(ServerName);
   except
        WriteLn('Unable to start Word.');
   Exit;
end;

w:= UTF8Decode('c:\mydoc.docx');
Server.Visible := True;  {Make Word visible}
Doc := Server.Documents.Open(w); 

Doc.Range.Text := 'This is a Heading';
Doc.Range.Font.Bold := True;
Doc.Format.SpaceAfter := 24; 
end.
```

Whereas this, based on the code above, in attempting to print a string at a bookmark, opens the document, retains the contents, moves to the bookmark and then does nothing.

```
w:= UTF8Decode('c:\mydoc.docx');
Server.Visible := True;  
Doc := Server.Documents.Open(w); 

oPara := Doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(Doc.Bookmarks.Item('\Bookmark1').Range);
oPara := Doc.Range.Text('Where will this appear if at all!');
```

Comment: Well for a start this is wrong! oPara := Doc.Range.Text('Where will this appear if at all!');

Answer (score 1):

Ah I worked it out. The following code works as expected:

```
program officAuto;

{$IFDEF FPC}
  {$MODE Delphi}
{$ELSE}
  {$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$ENDIF}

uses
   SysUtils, Variants, ComObj;

var
  Server, Connect : Variant;
  oWord, oPara1, oPara2 : Variant;

  w:widestring;

  begin
    if Assigned(InitProc) then
    TProcedure(InitProc);

  try
    Server := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
  except
    WriteLn('Unable to start Word.');
    Exit;
  end;


  // oWord := Server.Documents.Add;
  w:= UTF8Decode('c:\mydoc.docx');
  Server.Visible := True;  
  Server.Documents.Open(w); 

  oPara1 := Server.ActiveDocument.Content.Paragraphs.Add;
  oPara1.Range.Text := 'This is a Heading';
  oPara1.Range.Font.Bold := True;
  oPara1.Format.SpaceAfter := 24;
  oPara1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

  oPara2 := Server.ActiveDocument.Content.Paragraphs.Add;
  oPara2.Range.Text := 'Where will this appear if at all!';
  oPara2.Range.Font.Bold := False;
  oPara2.Format.SpaceAfter := 24;
  oPara2.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
end.
```